# Printing/displaying coordinate system of several raster files using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, coordinate-system

How can I extract the Coordinate System of many raster files (GeoTIFF) so the information is displayed, and I can ascertain that all of them are correctly settled in the same projection, using ArcPy?

The ideal would be not to load the files as it is too time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SpatialReference object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/spatialreference.htm) which can be accessed using Describe has the name property:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'X:\somefolderwithrasters'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for r in rasters:
    spatref = arcpy.Describe(r).spatialReference
    print 'Raster: {0} has spatial reference: {1}'.format(r, spatref.name)
```

Example output:

```
Raster: s1milj.tif has spatial reference: SWEREF99_TM
```